# WOPI online office add-in integration

Tags: office365, office-addins, word-addins, ms-wopi

I would like to auto load my add-in into Online Office 365 Word.

According to the documentation I created a host page with POST form, which is calling url from discovery request. I included ?sftc=1 parameter, to enable supportsFrameTrustedPostMessage.

```
<form id="office_form" name="office_form" target="office_frame" action="https://FFC-word-edit.officeapps.live.com/we/wordeditorframe.aspx?sftc=1&WOPISrc=https://fileUrl" method="post">
<input name="access_token" value="xxxx" type="hidden"/>
<input name="access_token_ttl" value="yyyy" type="hidden"/>
<input name="host_install_addins" value='[{"addinId": "WA104380121", "type": "TaskPaneApp"}]' type="hidden"/>
```

After page is loaded, office app should send postMessage ***App_IsFrameTrusted***, which is a handshake initialisation. Reply from host page should be ***Host_IsFrameTrusted***.

The problem is, that office doesn't send this ***App_IsFrameTrusted*** post message.

Here's the list of post messages, which are received by host page:
[image]
Does anybody have an experience with such issue? Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can you post your javascript too? It should be something like:

```
function handlePostMessage(e) {

    // The actual message is contained in the data property of the event.
    var msg = JSON.parse(e.data);

    // The message ID is now a property of the message object.
    var msgId = msg.MessageId;

    console.log('Received PostMessage ' + msgId + ' from ' + e.origin);

    if (msgId === 'App_IsFrameTrusted') {

        // Post back Host_IsFrameTrusted
        var msg = {
            "MessageId": "Host_IsFrameTrusted",
            "SendTime": Date.now(),
            "Values": {
                "isTopFrameTrusted": true // Hack
            }
        };

        // Check e.origin is expected origin
        e.source.postMessage(msg, e.origin);
    }
}
window.addEventListener('message', handlePostMessage, false);
```

Comment: Many thanks for an answer Nick, that's exactly what I have there, also the logging is very similar :) But the condition has never positive result, because the message with id 'App_IsFrameTrusted ' is not send at all by office app. Please see my original message, I added the list of received post messages. If you have working implementation, can you please share the code of your post form? Thank you!

Comment: Assuming that your JS is adding the event listener properly, the other (crazy) thing I would suggest is adding the sftc=1 parameter to the end of the action url. I have a few working WOPI implementations and they all have the parameter at the end! It shouldn't make any difference, but this is WOPI....

Comment: I can't believe it, but it's true :) Thanks a lot Nick! it works. Or at least it sends the App_IsFrameTrusted message. But the add in is still not loaded. Do I set correctly "host_install_addins" hidden field? Or is there anything else what needs to be done to load the addin? thanks

Comment: Have you requested Add-Ins to be enabled by CSPP? They take up to four weeks after you have requested it. Your JSON is perfect! If you're still struggling with this, I can do a screen share next week and help you out (my company specializes in WOPI).

Comment: Hi Nick, thanks, let me double check with CSPP team, if that not helps then I would really appreciate your help and a screen share call.